# Is there a way to cheaply transfer (plunge by pushing) a viscous liquid in to another container without plunger-to-tube discharge?

Tags: titration

Could anyone offer a suggestion as to how an economy-minded chemist ought to implement a DIY-ed positive displacement alternative to the following:

[image: failure]

Comment: You can't link to an attachment in your email, you can download it somewhere and then add the link, and someone with enough rep will edit it in for you.

Comment: A rock would work.  But a more useful answer would require some indication of what you want to accomplish.

Comment: I need to plunge (pull) and transfer (plunge by pushing) a viscous liquid in to another container without plunger-to-tube discharge.

Comment: I do not understand your question.  Have a look at the link and see if you can find something similar, follow the picture links and read up to describe your situation and help with common names for the things and actions you propose.  -  https://www.google.com/search?q=dispensing+cartridge&tbm=isch